# Calculate the distance between the points $(1, 2, \dots, n)$ and $(2, 3, \dots, n, 1)$

Tags: metric-spaces, arithmetic, coordinate-systems

I know that the operation to find the distance between two vectors is:

$$\sqrt{(b_1-a_1)^2+(b_2-a_2)^2+...+(b_n-a_n)^2}.$$

So the distance between $(7, 5, 3, 1)$ and $(1, 3, 5, 7)$ is:

$$\sqrt{(1-7)^2+(3-5)^2+(5-3)^2+(7-1)^2} = \sqrt{80}.$$

The distance between $(1, 2, \dots, n)$ and $(0, 0, \dots, 0, 0)$ is:

$$\sqrt{(0-1)^2+(0-2)^2+\dots+(0-n-1)^2+(0-n)^2} = \|(1, 2,\dots, n)\|.$$

But what about the distance between $(1, 2, \dots,n)$ and $(2,3, \dots,n, 1)$?

$$\sqrt{(2-1)^2+(3-2)^2+\dots+(n-n-1)^2+(1-n)^2} = \sqrt{1 + 1 +\dots+ 1 + (1-n)^2} = ?$$

I think the result is $n-1$, because it adds one to one up to $\sqrt{(1-n)^2} = n-1$, but I'm not sure.

Someone can help me solve this?

Comment: Your idea is fine, but your algebra is a little off: the sum inside the square root is $(n-1)+(1-n)^2=n(n-1)$, not $(1-n)^2$.

Comment: Sorry, I forget the last term! :)

Comment: Why its n(n-1)?

Comment: You have $n-1$ terms that are $1$, and you have one term that is $(1-n)^2=(n-1)^2$. Thus, you have $$(n-1)+(n-1)^2=(n-1)\Big(1+(n-1)\Big)=n(n-1)\;.$$

Comment: Don't forget that whenever you think you have the final formula, you can reality-check it by doing specific cases (like $n=3$, $n=5$) by hand and checking whether the numerical answer fits your formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

$$\underbrace{1 + 1 + \dots + 1}_{n-1} + (1 - n)^2 = (n - 1) + (n - 1)^2 = (n-1)[1 + (n - 1)] = (n-1)n$$

where the first equality used the fact that

$$(1 - n)^2 = [(-1)(n-1)]^2 = (-1)^2(n-1)^2 = (n-1)^2.$$

Therefore your calculation shows that

$$\|(2, 3, \dots, n, 1) - (1, 2, \dots, n-1, n)\| = \sqrt{n(n-1)}.$$